# yii : how to redirect to different page after logged in?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

Q : how to redirect to different page after logged in?

status : I've custom user role and I want to redirect to different page for different user.

> e.g hr manager -> employee/index, account manager -> account/index.

I'm using yii 1.1.xx and rights module. yii and rights module are going with green.

update question's info

this is the rank tbl 
[image]

this is user tbl
[image]

If the rank is Account Manager, the web site will redirect to account/index.

If the rank is HR manager, the web site will redirect to employee/index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('hrManager',Yii::app()->user->getId())==1)
{
    $this->redirect(array("employee/index"));
} else if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('accountManager',Yii::app()->user->getId())==1) {
    $this->redirect(array("account/index"));
}
```

Where `hrManager` and `accountManager` are the corresponding access rules for the HR Manager and Account Manager logins. This will check to see if the user has 'HR Manager' level access, if so redirect them there, and then checks if the user has 'Account Manager' level access, if so redirects them to that page.

Obviously you can customise to how it suits your app, as the above code won't redirect anywhere if the user has neither HR Manager or Account Manager access, so you'll need another catcher.

Edit:

The `hrManager` string is the rbac authitem name, do you have tables `authassignment`
 `authitem` and `authitemchild` set up for your rbac?

If not, you can use this method a little differently using your ranking table. you can either set it up using the rank_id, but you'd have to load the user model (if you haven't already got it loaded) which might not be the most efficient way of doing it.

```
$user = User::model()->findbyPk(Yii::app()->user->getId());
if($user->rank_id==3)
{
    $this->redirect(array("employee/index"));
} else if($user->rank_id==2)) {
    $this->redirect(array("account/index"));
}
```

The other way would be to load the users rank into the Yii::app()->user param after login so you don't have to load the user model before the redirect, maybe you have this set up already for however you are granting access to pages?

```
if(Yii::app()->user->rank_id==3)
{
    $this->redirect(array("employee/index"));
} else if(Yii::app()->user->rank_id==2)) {
    $this->redirect(array("account/index"));
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. pls look. is the 'hrmanager' an action of controller? I want to verify with the rank and redirect the specify page by rank.

Comment: @tharsoe, I've updated the answer with a few more details that might help, depending on how your app is set up.

Comment: Depends how you'd want to use it. If you are preventing one certain page from being viewed by a given usergroup, you could put this at the beginning of your controller action you are wanting to hide.

Comment: No ... i'm referring to question topic. I want user to be redirect to different page after login. Where's the right place to insert this code? LoginForm, CWebUser .. UserIdentity ? where ?

Comment: Do you have an `actionLogin` method in your site controller, you can add the redirect after you detect a valid login, something like; `if($model->validate() && $model->login()) { // code here }`

Comment: Ah.. ok, found, and implement with success [my user will be grateful to you ]

Answer (score 3):

Something like `$this->redirect(array("controller/admin"));` ?

Comment: yes I knew how to redirect. but I don't know how to redirect by user's role. e.g after logging in the user by hr manager role(rank), the page will be redirect to employee/index page.