# Redirection not working in yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I was trying to redirect after signin in yii framework but its not working i want to redirect to customer/dashboard after signin here's the code i am working

```
 public function actionLogin() {
        if (Yii::app()->user->getId() !== null) {
                $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('customer/dashboard');   
                $this->redirect($url);   


           // $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('customer/dashboard'));
        }
        $this->layout = "main";



        $model = new LoginForm;



        $this->title = "Login";


        if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
        }

        // collect user input data
        if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
            // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
            if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
                // we are now redirecting to the home page after login instead (as 
                // in update note above). IF the user is not applying for a job.
                $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('customer/dashboard');
                $this->redirect($url);


               // $this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('customer/dashboard'));
            } else {
                $_SESSION['pageName'] = "/UserEvents/LoginError";
            }
        }
        // display the login form
        $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
    }
```

IN that i am using actionLogin function to login

regards

Comment: Too much of code, please include only code which you get trouble with

Comment: It's difficult to find your problem that you put the whole controller.

Comment: check now i gave login script

Comment: *its not working* - can you also explain what result you get ? an error message or anything else ?

Comment: its showing blankpage after login

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104472/yii-how-to-redirect-to-different-page-after-logged-in

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code `Yii::app()->createUrl('customer/dashboard');` to `Yii::app()->urlManager->createUrl('customer/dashboard')`. Also you can pass an array to `redirect()` function and Yii will take care of generating correct url  `$this->redirect(['customer/dashboard']);`

Comment: i used  Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('customer/dashboard'); if used $this->redirect(['customer/dashboard']); not working

Comment: which version of yii you use ? Yii::$app is yii2 analog of Yii::app() in yii1

Comment: its redirection but its not going to customer/dashboard its going to signin  check from this by  registration http://majestic.6elements.net/majesticxpress/

Comment: `var_dump($url);die;`after you get it after call to `createUrl('customer/dashboard')` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81232/discussion-between-madu-and-tony).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use createUrl function then follow below pattern

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->createUrl('/modulename/controllername/action'));
```

And If you want to redirect without createUrl then use below one

```
$this->redirect(array('controllername/action'));
```

Comment: Please check the redirecting url, is it working without redirecting or not ?                     If yes then check Yii::app()->request->pathInfo for this and compare  with  $url = Yii::app()->createUrl('customer/dashboard'); $url value. both should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for redirect.

```
if (Yii::app()->user->getId() !== null) {

      $this->redirect(array("customer/dashboard"));   

      }
```